# Insert SQLite usando um array - PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, sqlite

Eu tenho o seguinte `array`:

```
array:30 [▼
  0 => "12933"
  1 => "12931"
  2 => "12930"
  3 => "12929"
  4 => "12928"
  5 => "12927"
  6 => "12926"
  7 => "12925"
  8 => "12924"
  9 => "12923"
  10 => "12922"
  11 => "12921"
  12 => "12920"
  13 => "12919"
  14 => "12918"
  15 => "12917"
  16 => "12916"
  17 => "12915"
  18 => "12914"
  19 => "12913"
  20 => "12912"
  21 => "12911"
  22 => "12910"
  23 => "12909"
  24 => "12908"
  25 => "12907"
  26 => "12906"
  27 => "12905"
  28 => "12904"
  29 => "12903"
]
```

Minha aplicação está usando uma base de produção `SQLServer` e tenho outra base `SQLITE` que eu tenho somente 2 tabelas de consulta e nessa base, uma tabela chamada `Notas` com somente uma coluna de nome `Numero`.

Eu estou tentando dar um `insert` nessa tabela, no qual cada `array` seria um registro, porém, como eu nunca fiz isso, não estou conseguindo, estou tentando o seguinte código:

```
$insertNumeroNotas = DB::connection('sqlite')
     ->insert('insert into Notas (Numero) values (?)', $quantidadeNotas);
```

no qual `$quantidadeNotas` é o `array`.

Eu preciso primeiro iterar por esse array pra depois dar o `insert`, ou o `insert` precisa ser dado em cada iteração desse array?

Comment: fjurr deu certo a resposta?

Comment: deu sim Virgilio, valeu mesmo

Comment: se puder aceitar como resposta @fjurr

Comment: pronto, tinha esquecido disso... valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um `foreach` e envolva o código da sua pergunta mudando o parâmetro para que a cada interação grave o item de cada posição do `array`:

```
foreach($quantidadeNotas as $n)
{
    DB::connection('sqlite')
        ->insert('insert into Notas (Numero) values (?)', [$n]);
}
```

essa forma seria uma das maneiras a outra seria com:

```
DB::connection('sqlite')
      ->table('Notas')
      ->insert(array_map(function($i)
            { return ['Numero' => $i]; }, 
       $quantidadeNotas));
```

é uma outra forma onde o próprio algoritmo resolve o `array`.

***Referencias:***

- [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database)
- [Using Multiple Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections)
- [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)